# Shortcut key for moving cards up or down in Trello

Tags: trello, keyboard-shortcuts, trello-cards

Is there a keyboard shortcut that moves Trello cards up or down in list order?

I want to prioritize cards without dragging and dropping.

Answer (score 10):

Currently the feature you want is not implemented. The only way to prioritise cards without drag and drop is moving all cards out of the list and move card with the highest priority first back to the list.

Comment: Yes... we need that feature. Can't wait to have it. Also it's strange that Trello supports J and K keys, but for left and right only arrows. And yet it is still so awesome :)

Comment: @Agzam `J` and `K` just select different cards (equivalent to `←` and `→`), `<` and `>` actually move the selected card.

Comment: But why not use shift + `J` and shift + `K` to move up and down cards?

Comment: Are there any updates for this?

Comment: Still not done: https://trello.com/c/3qLapR5l

Comment: There still is no real keyboard shortcut, but you can hit "e" for the quick menu, and then in chrome, use the command+f and ctrl-enter trick to find the "move" menu entry, click, and then find the "position" text box, "click" it with the ctrl-enter trick, then hit tab and you're at the position select box. voila

Comment: you can use , . < >   to move cards to top/bottom of adjacent lists (press ? for shortcuts)

Answer (score 7):

The [Shortcusts for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcuts-for-trello/pfkeglfbhfmlnapfjfjfkiipclpmanim) Chrome Extension lets you move cards to the top. It's open source and there is [a GitHub Issue](https://github.com/bulkan/shortcuts-for-trello/issues/6) on it to add shortcut for *Card Move Up/Down*. (Any JS developers willing to pull this one off?)

Comment: UPDATE: The developers implemented the feature! ITS WORKING!! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcuts-for-trello/pfkeglfbhfmlnapfjfjfkiipclpmanim?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

I actually recently discovered Dynalist which allows me to hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button and arrow keys to move the priority.  Highly recommended!